# Error in setup wizard

Tags: magento2, setup, web-setup-wizard, http-error-500

1. When I went to **system configuration** in **Setup Wizard** to enter and save my keys, it saved them but then gave me the following error: 
   `Command "show" failed: [InvalidArgumentException] Package magento/framework not found show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [package] [version]`
2. when I go to Component Manager, it just spins non stop. If I look at the Chrome code inspector, I see the following 500 error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)   /setup/index.php/componentGrid/components

Any help would be appretiated!

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in your root installation folder:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf vendor/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vvv ; 
mage deploy:mode:set developer;
mage setup:upgrade ;
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I tried running the commands one by one, got a bunch of errors at composer install && composer update, and then every other command after that. Put my site down. 

So I ended up restoring my site. Now I'm back where I started. Is there a manual way (through FTP) that I can do this? I know SSH, just not that advanced to spot if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: seems like your installation was thought the Github clone, so try to replace or reset the files to the originals and then disable all third-party extensions to test.